Android working fine but iOS returns an error regarding React-Codegen from project Pods
created a new react native app with npx react-native init myapp
and pod installed
npm start and then i for ios emulator
Android working fine but iOS returns an error regarding React-Codegen from project Pods
Explicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in stopped when running ios emulator in react native
stopped forever in terminal
and in Xcode below error
React codegen Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
when runnign android and ios builds to be sucessfull

i have the same issue. could you find a solution?
